# Use ethernet for wake on lan and use wifi after turned on?

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, wakeonlan

I would like to turn on my computer using wake-on-lan using the wired ethernet port.

Once the computer is turned on, I would like it to only use the configured wifi connection.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

(I am running Ubuntu 19.10. Both ethernet and wifi work on my computer, so there is no connectivity issues).

Comment: Are you  looking something like that?  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-wireless-wake-on-lan-for-linux-wifi-wowlan-card/

Comment: I’d like to have the computer completely turned off, rather than in a sleep state. My mother board supports Ethernet wake-on-lan when the computer is completely powered off. I’d like to use this feature to turn on the computer, and then communicate with it using the WiFi adapter, after the computer has booted the OS (Ubuntu). Nevertheless, the link you provided is a valuable option, if I can’t get it to work the way I want.